# Compress a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I do have an array called **$output**. If i do the following ...

```
<?php
print_r($output);
?>
```

... the contents of the array look like this ...

```
Array ( [id] => 116 [the_key] => monday    [value] => 0 )
Array ( [id] => 116 [the_key] => tuesday   [value] => 1 )
Array ( [id] => 116 [the_key] => wednesday [value] => 0 )
Array ( [id] => 133 [the_key] => monday    [value] => 0 )
Array ( [id] => 133 [the_key] => tuesday   [value] => 1 )
Array ( [id] => 133 [the_key] => wednesday [value] => 0 )
Array ( [id] => 127 [the_key] => monday    [value] => 0 )
Array ( [id] => 127 [the_key] => tuesday   [value] => 0 )
Array ( [id] => 127 [the_key] => wednesday [value] => 0 )
```

... but i would like to have the contents in a form like this ...

```
Array ( [id] => 116 [monday] => 0 [tuesday] => 1 [wednesday] => 0)
Array ( [id] => 133 [monday] => 0 [tuesday] => 1 [wednesday] => 0)
Array ( [id] => 127 [monday] => 0 [tuesday] => 0 [wednesday] => 0)
```

is there some method to do this without looping a million times through?

Comment: show how does that `$output` form in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this falls under "looping a million times through", but why not try grouping the items by `id`?

```
$newArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output); $i++) {
    $curr = $output[$i];
    $id = $curr["id"];
    $day = $curr["the_key"];
    $value = $curr["value"];
    if(array_key_exists($id, $newArray)) {
        $newArray[$id][$day] = $value;
    } else {
        $newArray[$id] = array($day => $value);
    }
}
```

From what I gather, `$newArray` should satisfy your spec.

Comment: Does your code not insert a new array level _$newArray['id']['day']_ while the OA is asking for a flat array of arrays with items _id_, _dayname_, _value_? Btw: I would suggest your solution with an array of arrays with key = id. It would not be a disadvantage when working with the array. And the new array could be created in one pass.

Comment: @hherger So it does. I'll edit it to change, but the point is that the algorithm is already there, and the asker has, for some reason, neglected to even think of manually rearranging the array.